# Binary Saving a Struct with Struct array members (C)?

Tags: c, dynamic, file-io, struct

I'm currently working on a program that uses these two structs:

```
//Struct to hold contact info about a friend
typedef struct
{
    char *firstName, *lastName;
    char *home, *cell;
} Friend;

//Struct to hold a list of friends and keep track of its size.
typedef struct
{
    Friend *listEntries;
    size_t listSize;
} FriendList;
```

Each of the string members within the `Friend` struct is dynamically allocated, as is the `listEntries` array inside `FriendList`. I'm trying to save a `FriendList` as a binary record, but when I try to do this using `fwrite()` and then read it back with `fread()`, the `listEntries` array of the `FriendList` that is read from the file is empty. Is there any way to save a dynamic struct like this?

**EDIT: The functions I use to read/write the struct are:**

```
void writeList(FriendList *fl, char* filename)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "wb+");

    if(fp != NULL)
    {
        fwrite(fl, sizeof(FriendList), 1, fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}

void readList(FriendList *dest, char* filename)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb");

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("oops...");
    }
    else
    {
        fread(dest, sizeof(FriendList), 1, fp);
    }

    close(fp);
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code that does the fread/fwrite.

Comment: Oops, dunno why I didn't do that at first DX. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must save the data the pointers point at, not the pointers themselves. Pointers are meaningless outside your process as it exists at the very moment, so saving a pointer value to disk means nothing.

In general, you cannot do this by using a single `fwrite()` to dump out a structure, since that will not follow the pointers.

You need to invent an actual external file format to use, and write code to save and load it. I would suggest a text-based format, since most of your data is text. [Perhaps CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)?

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense. I went back and changed the program to use a CSV-ish format for the file and it works perfectly. Thanks!